# Does heroku support static files now?

Tags: django, heroku

This is a basic question. The other day I was watching a video on youtube on deploying django application to heroku. In that video they went through amazon web services for static files. When I deployed django on heroku today all my static files are working. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, they have a document up on it now: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Answer (score 0):

Rename your index.html to home.html.
Create an index.php file with the following code:

```
<?php include_once("home.html"); ?>
```

Now go to your app folder in CMD (or Bash), and commit your code to Heroku using the following:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'Change this to a meaningful description'
git push heroku master
```

[Source](http://www.lemiffe.com/how-to-deploy-a-static-page-to-heroku-the-easy-way/)